# Creating an observable knockout array from a JSON response

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout-2.0

C#/MVC/Knockout/JSON

I've got the following javascript:

```
function Feed(data) {
    this.ID = ko.observable(data.ID);
    this.RSSName = ko.observable(data.RSSName);
    alert(data.RSSName + " " + data.ID);
}

function ViewModel() {
    self = this;
    self.CurrentFeeds = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.isLoading = ko.observable(false);
    self.StatusMessage = ko.observable("Loading");

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("RSSList", "RSS")',
        success: function (data) {
            var feeds = $.map(data, function (item) {
                alert(item.RSSName + " " + item.ID + " 1");
                return new Feed(item)
            });
            self.CurrentFeeds(feeds);
            //self.CurrentFeeds(data);

        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
        }
    });

    self.save = function () {
        self.deleteFeed = function (feed) {
        };
    };
}
```

The JSON response (as copied from fiddler) looks like this:

```
{"aaData":[{"ID":"0","RSSName":"Most Recent"},{"ID":"1","RSSName":"Website feed"}]}
```

Controller:

```
    public JsonResult RSSList()
    {
        var query = (from t in db.tblRSSFeeds
                     select new ViewModels.RSSList()
                     {
                         ID = t.pkID.ToString(),
                         RSSName = t.szFeedName
                     }).OrderBy( t => t.RSSName).ToList();

        var recent = new ViewModels.RSSList();
        recent.ID = "0";
        recent.RSSName = "Most Recent";
        query.Insert(0, recent);

        return Json(  query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I'm thinking my issue has to do with the Feed(data) function in that it's only passing back one record.  I tried setting the self.CurrentFeeds(data) as well with no luck.  The "alerts" shown above show undefined but I can see the data coming down from fiddler...

For some reason the success function isn't seeing the data correctly to create the array.  Why is this?

Comment: What should be the url for the get request?

Comment: Its /RSS/RSSList (I do see the data coming back in fiddler so I know its hitting the right URL...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is the response:

`{"aaData":[{"ID":"0","RSSName":"Most Recent"},{"ID":"1","RSSName":"Website feed"}]}`

Change the `success` callback to:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: '@Url.Action("RSSList", "RSS")',
   success: function (data) {
           var feeds = $.map(data.aaData, function (item) {
           alert(item.RSSName + " " + item.ID + " 1");
           return new Feed(item)
       });
       self.CurrentFeeds(feeds);
   },
   error: function (err) {
       alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
   }
});
```

And i belive it works, because you are trying to map an object not an array, so you must to get the `aaData` that is the array to map.

Comment: Bullseye. Thanks!  I was looking at aaData and trying to relate it to "data" in the function call (even changed the name to aaData.  But not data.aaData... I just tried that now and it worked!  Is aaData something that is automatic?

Comment: Nop, I belive not, but i need to see the `Action` to get more info.

Comment: I just added the action above.

Comment: Are you using some `Datable` plugin? _I ask that because it is the format expected by **jQuery Datatable**._

Comment: Interesting; I was...  But I thought I removed all references to that?  I don't see any artifacts from the previous workings...?  Would that be in the controller?

Comment: Nevermind; I was working with the wrong call, there was an artifact left return Json( new { aaData = query }, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet); I can't believe it was as simple as that.  Goes to show, you stare at the same code long enough; you don't see the errors. Thanks, Joel; much appreciated.